# Add one text to multiple files using bash

Tags: bash

I have many files with the extension `.com`, so the files are named `001.com`, `002.com`, `003.com`, and so on.

And I have another file called `headname` which contains the following information:

```
abc=chd
dha=djj
cjas=FILENAME.chk
dhdh=hsd
```

I need to put the information of the file headname inside (and at the begin of) the files `001.com`, `002.com`, `003.com` and so on... But `FILENAME` needs to be the filename of the file that will receive the `headname` information (without the `.com` extension).

So the output need to be:

For the `001.com`:

```
abc=chd
dha=djj
cjas=001.chk
dhdh=hsd
```

For the `002.com`:

```
abc=chd
dha=djj
cjas=002.chk
dhdh=hsd
```

For the `003.com`:

```
abc=chd
dha=djj
cjas=003.chk
dhdh=hsd
```

And so on...

Comment: Something like `for f in <files> ; do sed "s/FILENAME/$f/g' headname > "${f}.com" ; done`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
head=$(<headname)        # read head file into variable
head=${head//$'\n'/\\n}  # replace literal newlines with "\n" for sed
for f in *.com; do       # loop over all *.com files
  # make a backup copy of the file (named 001.com.bak etc).
  # insert the contents of $head with FILENAME replaced by the 
  # part of the filename before ".com" at the beginning of the file      
  sed -i.bak "1i${head/FILENAME/${f%.com}}" "$f"
done
```

Answer (score 4):

```
set -e

for f in *.com
do
    cat <(sed "s#^cjas=FILENAME.chk\$#cjas=${f%.com}.chk#" headname) "$f" > "$f.new"
    mv -f "$f.new" "$f"
done
```

Explanation:

- `for f in *.com` -- this loops over all file names ending with `.com`.
- `sed` is a program that can be used to replace text.
- `s#...#...#` is the substitute command.
- `${f%.com}` is the file name without the `.com` suffix.
- `cat <(...) "$f"` -- this merges the new head with the body of the `.com` file.
- The output of `cat` is stored into a file named `123.com.new` -- `mv -f "$f.new" "$f"` is used to rename `123.com.new` to `123.com`.

Comment: Process substitution is an unnecessary complication here; `sed ... | cat - "$f" > "$f.new"`